# band pass filter does it use fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform, signal-processing

I am doing a course on signal processing which we have focused on fourier transform.

I have also come across band pass filters. This is all very new to me so apologies if its a stupid question.

I think I understand band pass filters from a high level in that if you pass a signal and two frequencies say 5Hz & 15Hz the band pass function will ignore any frequencies outside this range. My question is how does it do this, does it have to use fourier tansforms to get the underlying frequencies of the signal then remove the signals which frequencies are outside the range specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, from a practical perspective, a bandpass filter (or at least the devices I've worked with so far) doesn't exactly 'remove' the frequencies, even though it looks like that; it just attenuates them enough so that your system works as if they weren't there. You take the cutoff frequencies into account at design time to create a filter that suits your needs.

Now, from a more mathematical perspective, you can actually transform your signal, remove any component outside the frequency range you specify, and then get the resulting signal back to use it wherever you need it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So band pass filters and fourier transforms can be used separately to 'filter' certain frequencies of a signal. Also I guess they can be used to together but that is probably not the 'normal' practise

Comment: Well, I've actually done that in a project some time ago, and I've seen people create a digital filter that uses FFT to create/filter a signal in real time, so what you do to filter a signal depends on what you need, mostly